# AJAX SlideshowExtender Troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am having trouble getting the AJAX slideshow extender to work. It will not rotate the images on the page. The strange thing is is that it will create an img tag outside of the  tag at the bottom of the page when it renders in the browser and rotate the images there, something like this

```
<img style=" display:none;" src="the rotating images" />
```

It will not supply or rotate an image inside the target control though. My code is as follows:

.aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Slideshow.aspx.cs" Inherits="MirandasWebsite.Slideshow" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Miranda's Slideshow</title>
<link href="Styles/Mir3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smSlideshow" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="Images">
    <asp:Image ID="mySlideshow" runat="server" Height="250" Width="300"  />
</div>
<asp:SlideShowExtender ID="Slideshowextender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="SSBehaviorID"
    TargetControlID="mySlideshow" SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides" AutoPlay="true"
    NextButtonID="btnNext" PreviousButtonID="btnPrev" PlayButtonID="btnPlay" PlayButtonText="Play"
    StopButtonText="Stop" Loop="true">
</asp:SlideShowExtender>
<div id="slideshowDescription" runat="server">
</div>
<div class="centerControls">
<asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" Text="Previous" />
<asp:Button ID="btnPlay" runat="server" Text="" />
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the codebehind

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {
        DataTable table = SiteAccess.GetImages();
        AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] imgSlide = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[table.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            imgSlide[i] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide(row["Full"].ToString(), String.Empty, String.Empty);
            i++;
        }

        return (imgSlide);
    }
```

Any clues as to why this is happening. I have tried everything I can think of including hardcoding in  the images, but I still get the same results.